# Why is this Iota-specific database question off topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I can see that question [What are the length for address and seed](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/what-are-the-length-for-address-and-seed) was marked as "This question does not appear to be about Iota". The OP is asking about the length of IOTA addresses, so I am wondering:

- What made this question be "off-topic"?
- What should have been made clearer by the OP?
- When down-voting (I see at least 3 down-votes), should we leave a comment justifying the down-vote? As it stands, there is no comment explaining to the OP why his question was received negatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [revisions](https://iota.stackexchange.com/posts/1273/revisions) of the question you can see that the question was closed when it read like this:

> For Mysql or Postgresql, what are the best column's type for storing addresses and seeds?

Honestly, I didn't know what that was even supposed to mean. The clarification about length of the field only came afterwards. Now it's—from my view—related enough to IOTA and clear enough to be answered. A bit trivial maybe and certainly not indicating a lot of research by the OP but also not that much in need of closure.